# What is the use of where keyword in a generic function's signature?

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, refactoring, rx-java

I refactored this snippet:

```
remark.observeOn(mainThread())
      .subscribe { remark ->
          remark_box.visible = remark.isNotEmpty()
          remark_tv.text = remark
      }
      .addTo(CompositeDisposable())
```

using this extension, but I get lost from what is `: Disposable where T : Observable<String>`
Please somebody could shed some light on that?

```
remark.bindTo(remark_tv)
      .addTo(CompositeDisposable())
```

and

```
fun <T> T.bindTo(textView: TextView): Disposable where T : Observable<String> {
    return observeOn(mainThread())
        .subscribe { remark ->
            textView.text = remark
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`: Disposable` Signifies that your function's return type is `Disposable`.
and `where T : Observable<String>` part specifies an [`upper` `bound`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#upper-bounds) on the `generic` type parameter `T`. in simple terms it means `T` must be a `subtype` of `Observable<String>`.

When working with `generic` `types`, you can specify a single `upper` `bound` as

```
// This function can only be called with types implementing Collection<Int>
fun <T: Collection<Int>> someFun(first: T, second: T)

// If you try to call it as following, it will not compile
someFun(listOfStrings, listOfStrings)
```

***but if you need to specify multiple `upper` `bounds` then you have to use the `where` `clause`*** as

```
// This function can only be called with types implementing Iterable<Int>
// as well as Serializable
fun <T> someFun(first: T, second: T): Int where  T: Iterable<Int>,T: Serializable

// This does not work, you can not comma separate the upper bounds
fun <T: Iterable<Int>, Serializable> someFun(first: T, second: T): Int
```

As the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#upper-bounds) states

> Only one upper bound can be specified inside the angle brackets. If
>   the same type parameter needs more than one upper bound, we need a
>   separate where-clause.